# Simple circuit Voltage regulator question?

Tags: batteries, voltage, voltage-regulator, heat

I am trying to build a simple circuit that takes a 9v battery through a voltage regulator that outputs 1.5v across a load resistor . The load will be just a piece of metal that gets heated up.

My initial understanding of voltage regulators was wrong. I thought I wouldn't be wasting a lot of power using one, but from further reading I have discovered that they are just used for rectifying an ac source and when (vi-vout) is a large number a lot of power is dissipated/wasted as heat in the regulator. I want as much of the power from the battery as possible to be dissipated across the load resistor @ 1.5v.

So, my questions is how can I build this circuit with a 9v input and a 1.5v across load dissipated as heat with the smallest amount of wasted power through a regulator or other components?

Comment: You need a switchmode converter. But how much heat are you expecting to get? 1 Watt would be a lot of power for a 9V battery.

Comment: Somewhere from 175 degrees C to 200 degrees C. I am going to use a load with a high resistance. So this switchmode converter won't dissipate a significant amount of power? I was hoping to make this as efficient as possible. Thanks.

Comment: I read up on switch mode converters and can see that they are significantly more efficient than using a voltage regulator. Thanks.

Comment: Do you think the LM25576 would be a good choice for my application? : http://www.ti.com/product/lm25576#buy                                                    Thanks.

Comment: I asked "how much heat", not "what temperature". What is it you're heating up, and how fast does it lose heat to the environment?

Comment: It's a mesh metal mesh. This was the one I found on amazon:http://www.amazon.com/Stainless-Steel-Perforated-Sheet-Length/dp/B005H3GTJ6/ref=sr_1_5?s=industrial&ie=UTF8&qid=1362286762&sr=1-5&keywords=stainless+steel+mesh. I'm not sure of the dimensions just yet, but approximately 2x2 inches.

Comment: Don't want to discourage you, but heating that up will take a lot more current than your average 9V battery can supply.

Comment: I have had multiple sources tell me that the mesh will create sufficient resistance to provide that heat

Answer (score 2):

Couple of $0.02 thoughts.

1. Can you use a heater with higher resistance so that it can run directly off 9V?  Then you wouldn't need a regulator.
2. Pulse-width modulation (PWM).  Connect the load through a MOSFET (or a BJT) to the battery.  PWM signal is applied to the MOSFET gate.  In this approach, PWM duty cycle controls the RMS voltage across the heater.
3. [Buck converter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter) is a type of a switch-mode power supply.  It's more complex that, say, a linear regulator, but is can have 90% efficiency.   May be, you can find an integrated power supply module [like this one](http://www.murata-ps.com/data/meters/dms-78xxsr.pdf), which would suit your input voltage and output voltage & current.  If you can't find a module, you can roll your own.
   **edit:**  LM25576 mentioned above is an IC around which a buck converter can be built.  *"Buck converter"* and *"step down switching converter"* can be used pretty much interchangeably.

Comment: 1. I could, but would the 9v last as long without some kind of regulation? Do you think I would be better off just using a higher resistance? I am trying to make this device work for as long as possible on one battery.  So do you think it would lose less power with a higher resistance and no switch mode converter. Or a lower resistance with the switch mode converter?                                                   2. Would a buck converter work better than the  LM25576 mentioned above? Thanks.